# How to load specific ArcGIS vector tile layer using OL?

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-rest-api, vector-tiles

We have a react application using OpenLayers.
We want to load a grayscale background layer.
I found one at https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=0a24e94a70934c6f8224f77bd1edeed4 and then change the map to 'Modern Antique'.

Next I'm trying to load this layer, but how to select the 'Modern Antique' layers?
So far I've got this:

```js
var newGrayScaleLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
      format: new MVT(),
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      url: "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_GCS_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf"
    }),
  });
```

But this is not loading the correct layer.
The URL `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf` is also working but again not the correct layer.

Looking in ESRI's viewer I see the URL for all layers are the same, but it starts loading some json files first. One of them contains the layer name.
But I don't see how to set it using OpenLayers.

If this is an issue with ArcGis data I can also use a different source, but couldn't find another nice looking grayscale background provider.

Comment: Vector tiles contain only data.  You need a style to display them.  You can use ol-mapbox-style as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-style.html but there is currently a bug in the way ol-mapbox-style reads Esri tile urls, which can be fixed by a patch to the load function https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-cohen-40cjt

Comment: Thanks @Mike, your example is working fine. But when we add it to our code the wrong pbf is requested. First of all, we are centered in the middle of Africa but still the first tile is requested: `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer///tile/0/0/0.pbf` and also look at the 3(!) slashed before tile. Whe're also using OL v6.4.3